# Javascript : Download '.doc' file from xml template

Tags: javascript

I have a REST service which returns a xml template for msword document. The template looks like the following one,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels"
        pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"
        pkg:padding="512">
        <pkg:xmlData>
           ....
           ....
           ....
           ....
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

In my JavaScript, I have written the following code to download the template as word document.

```
 $http.post(url,postdata).then(
      function(restResponse){
         window.location.href = 'data:application/msword;charset=utf-8;' + restResponse.data;
      },
      function(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
);
```

But If I open the downloaded word file, it says the contents are not proper and MsWord cannot open the downloaded file. Which is the proper way to make this work?

Comment: could the rest service return a URL instead and you request it instead of the data?

Comment: The backend is not modifiable and it is an already existing system. The template is stored in database and the REST service modifies the template with dynamic content and returns it. If I invoke the REST service with some REST clients like 'DHC' , I am able to download and open the document properly. The problem occurs only if I download it via Javascript code.

Comment: how are you getting the restResponse? could that be the url you actually need to use?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I have modified the javascript code now to show how I am invoking the REST service using AngularJs $http service.

Comment: i would ask the developer of the service how they want it.

Comment: Try parsing the data in UTF-8 format and then open it in word.